# Blender 3.3 Generate Rig Button is deactivated

Tags: rigify

Why is the "Generate Rig" button grayed out, or what is missing here? I have spent hours unsuccessfully trying to find a solution to this problem.

Is it possible to generate a rig without this button. I need your help please.

[image]

---

@Crantisz, this is the metarig to which I want to generate a rig:

[image]

Comment: Have you selected the metarig?

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: @Crantisz, which file should I share ?

Comment: copy armature, save it to blend file and upload at https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Share the file, not a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution by starting from the beginning: the version of the face armature is not up to date and as I accept to update the version, it creates the problem to generate the rig and to deactivate the button to Re-generate. A blocked loop.
Here my question would be how to update the Rigify add-on to be compatible with the version of the armature provided in blender 3.3.1?

Comment: You really shouldn't add questions to answers submit another question otherwise it won'y really get seen as a question.